# Is there no problem when par rate is used for IRS stress-test?

Tags: interest-rates, interest-rate-swap

I want to do stress-test such as principle component analysis on IRS(interest rate swap) in order to calculate risk for the future change in interest rate. However it is so confusing **which interest rate(par rate, spot rate, forward rate)** should I use for stress-test. Most of papers I read use spot rate. There are also some studies using forward rate (ref.1). One research used par rate and compared to spot rate(ref.2).

Question is that **is there no problem when par rate is used for IRS stress-test?**
I think the fact that par(swap) rate includes several cash flows makes some problem (dirty price? something like that)

Thank you in advance.

-------------------   ref.  -------------------

ref.1: Ilias Lekkos, A Critique of Factor Analysis of Interest Rates, The Journal of Derivates, 2000
ref.2: http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/%5BSalomon%20Smith%20Barney%5D%20Principles%20of%20Principal%20Components%20-%20A%20Fresh%20Look%20at%20Risk,%20Hedging%20and%20Relative%20Value.pdf

Comment: The rates you stress should be the rates that you use for modelling / valuation. If you build your curves from par rates, stress those and re-bootstrap. If you build from zeros, you can directly stress those.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We generate zero curve from par rate using interpolation and bootstrapping, and then calculate NPV using zero curve. Based on your comment, we should stress on the zero curve.